# jQuery conditionals & Ajax problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, conditional-statements

I'm writing a form that will change all of the user's profile settings. I have the HTML and PHP set up correctly and working, but using jQuery conditionals & Ajax is proving to be a problem.

It should validate for an email if one is there. Then, it should make sure the change isn't a password change (if it is, make sure passwords match then post), then post if the form was valid. It seems to not consider any of the conditionals and post regardless.

```
     $("profSet").validate({
        rules: {
            chem: {
                email: true
            }
        }
     });

    $('#subSet').live('click',function() {
        if($("#chfn").val() == 0 && $("#chln").val() == 0 && $("#chpw").val() == 0 && $("#chpw2").val() == 0 && $("#chem").val() == 0)
        {
            if($("#profSet").valid())
            {
                if($("#chpw").val() == "" && $("#chpw2").val() == "")
                {
                    $.post('php/profSet.php', $('#profSet').serialize(), function(){
                        $('#profSet').hide();
                        $('#success').show();
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    if($("#chpw").val() == $("#chpw2").val())
                    {
                        $.post('php/profSet.php', $('#profSet').serialize(), function(){
                            $('#profSet').hide();
                            $('#success').show();
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#error').show();
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you put some semi-functioning code into a JSFiddle or something? There's no HTML Posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to declare a `var valid = true` at the beginning of your click method and set it to false if any of your checks fail, then at the end of your validation methods, perform the check `if(!valid) { e.preventDefault() }` to stop event propagation. Your handler does nothing to stop event propagation right now. In order to accomplish that, you should change your anonymous click handler function to accept the event as a parameter which I called "e" so that you can short-circuit the submission.